# Não consigo adicionar um item a uma array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Não estou conseguindo usar a função ADICIONAL
bom estou tentando fazer um cart que a pessoa pode adicionar o adicionais nos itens porem não estou conseguindo. sou novo na area de programação e estou desenvolvendo sistemas para estudos.

```
module.exports = function Cart(cart) {
this.items = cart.items || {};
this.totalItems = cart.totalItems || 0;
this.totalPrice = cart.totalPrice || 0;

this.add = function(item, id) {
    var cartItem = this.items[id];
    if (!cartItem) {
        cartItem = this.items[id] = {item: item, quantity: 0, price: 0, add: {adicional: null, quantidade: 0, preco:0}};
    }
    cartItem.quantity++;
    cartItem.price = cartItem.item.price * cartItem.quantity;
    this.totalItems++;
    this.totalPrice += cartItem.item.price;
};

this.adicional = function(item, id){
    this.items[id].item.add.adicional = item;
};

this.remove = function(id) {
    this.totalItems -= this.items[id].quantity;
    this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].price;
    delete this.items[id];
};

this.getItems = function() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var id in this.items) {
        arr.push(this.items[id]);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

};

Comment: E `cart.items` seria o que?

Comment: essa linha `this.items[id].item.add.adicional = item;` está bem estranha, não seria algo como `this.items[id] = item;` ou `this.items[id].adicional = item;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Algumas considerações, pare esse caso não tem retorno, então sua função adicional não precisa ser retornada para a variável this.adicional, pode declarar a funciotion normalmente. Nesse caso pode estar está retornando nulo por causa do this ou pela forma de inserir, eu prefiro usar o push para arrays, utilize dentro da função adicional a seguinte linha:

```
this.items.push(item);
```

remova o *this* caso retorne o erro abaixo:

```
    Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.
```

Sobre seu código, existem alguns erros aparentimente, não vi a chamada da função adicional com a passagem do parametro 'item'.

Em javascript a melhor forma de inserir um item no array é com push.

No inicio do código se o cart.items for nulo ele cria um objeto {}, sugiro criar um array e dentro desse array colocar vários objetos. Segue um exemplo. Para executar basta criar um arquivo server.js e fazer a chamada desse arquivo com node + caminho + nomeArquivo. Ex: node "e:\teste\src\server.js".

Segue o código de exemplo:

```
 const items = [];
 item = {item: 1, quantidade: 1}
 adicional(item);

 item = {item: 2, quantidade: 2}
 adicional(item);

 item = {item: 3, quantidade: 3}
 adicional(item);

 function adicional (item) {
      items.push(item);
 }

 console.log(items);
 // resultado
 // [
 //     { item: 1, quantidade: 1 },
 //     { item: 2, quantidade: 2 },
 //     { item: 3, quantidade: 3 }
 //   ]
```

Comment: Preciso por o adicional, no hamburg no id do hamburguer, cada hamburguer vai ter um adicional  , porem não achei uma solução ainda...

Comment: então Items é o hamburger e item são as coisas que vão no hamburger? Seria isso? Se sim você quer adicionar os itens extra no hamburger a partir de um id especifico. Nesse caso Items é um array com varios hamburgeres e cada um pode ter adicionais ou não? Acho legal você editar a sua pergunta e colocar os jsons para a gente entender melhor. Sem os models complica um pouco, mas basicamente o que te falei é a resposta. Você conseguiu testar meu código?